# My buttons & link hover stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

5th post here. I recently made a nav update on my portfolio page :

[My portfolio](http://farishtahaider.com)

and ever since, I cannot click on the links and my hover over links/i class items are not working. Could it have to do with the z-index? I have no other idea what it may be. The html/css/js was too long for stackoverflow so I put it on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle repo](https://jsfiddle.net/LaFrish/9h18o80c/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=9h18o80c#&togetherjs=tOHvr5jADV)

nav menu

```
#menuToggle a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;

  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;

  z-index: 10;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: #f91791;
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 3;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1600px;
    height: 1600px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;

  background: #f91791;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 115px;
}

#menu li hover{
  color: #fff;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

nav html

```
<section id="welcome">
        <header class="close">
            <nav role='navigation' id="menuToggle">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="#welcome">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#resume">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact Me</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: remove the 'z-index:1' from your h1; or conversely, add a z=index:0 if you haven't defined it yet.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I did take out the hero card like anthony suggested below.

Comment: There's no previous commit you can roll back to? The code is so massive, it's hard to know what we're looking for. What exact changes did you make to the nav? Also, you're calling 2 different jquery CDNs; in addition, you should really concatenate your scripts, you have more than a dozen of them. With all due respect, this page is coded as eloquently as the average wordpress page.. Again, needle in a haystack here..

Comment: https://github.com/LaFrish/lafrish.github.io backtrack your changes here, roll back and test; the joys of having a repository!

Comment: Thank you! I made the appropriate changes (it was the button & button before z-index) but now the text of the button is showing on the nav dropdown. I am going to just live with it but I am so curious on how to completely fix the problems. Also, I definitely know I have to go back and clean everything up and concate my scripts. Had to get the site up to apply for jobs per my bootcamps due date. I can go back now that the rush is over. I really really apprecate your help and would give you up points but I don't have enough points myself to do it. lol

Comment: Just give your nav a higher z-index and you're set. Go get 'em!

Comment: @LaFrish 5 questions so far.. 4 of which calling yourself "the noob" .. and you still haven't accepted an answer! Thanking people isn't good enough. Learn to accept an answer, people want to gain rep, and thats how. To accept an answer you hover beside the best one, and a check mark will appear. Click it and it will turn green. Answerer gets 15 rep, you get 2. When you have 15 rep you can vote people up too. You can vote up as many answers per q as u like, but only accept 1 per question. go do it!

Comment: @LaFrish 3 months by the way is not-so-new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "#welcome .hero" is covering the page. I don't really see it in use on the page. Maybe remove it since it doesn't look like you are going to use a hero image?

Comment: That helped with the hover! However ,the welcome to me button, in the header, is still not working.

Comment: Cool. Ill take a look again to see what might be causing it. Good on ya for jumping in the web arena.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I got the buttons to work but now the button text is showing in the nav overlay. lol I can't win. I am fine with them showing bc I rather have the functionality of the buttons. I am curious on how to fix it. I did update it in jsfiddle if you want to take a look later.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome Trish. Try adding z-index:0; to #welcome .welcome .button in your CSS (as well as to any other misbehaving buttons).

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on your page and click "inspect element", you will see some 404 errors. I suspect the page is unable to find these files, and you are losing the functionality within them.

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the colon in the

```
#menu li hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```

It should read:

```
#menu li:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how its supposed to look but if you change the header position to absolute (instead of fixed) the links do work.